# How do I fix merge conflic in pubspec.yaml and pubspec.lock?

Tags: git, yaml, flutter-dependencies, git-merge-conflict, pubspec

I stashed the recent change I have on my local machine, and then pull from the remote repository. Along the way, I encounted the below error. How can I merge my stash and also fix git conflict?

```
Auto-merging pubspec.yaml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in pubspec.yaml
Auto-merging pubspec.lock
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in pubspec.lock
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open those two files and the conflicts will be shown to you. Once you resolve them you can commit them and you will now have successfully merged.